# Having common validation function across multiple controller in laravel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Trying my hand on learning laravel.

I have a user form which post to this route

```
Route::post('users/add','usersController@store')->middleware('admin');
```

The store function in the usersController calls another function called validateForm which basically validates the input from the form ,like so

```
class usersController extends Controller
{
/*
 *Store a user in database
*/
function store(){
    $input=Request::all();

    // create the validation rules ------------------------
    $rules = array(
    'name'             => 'required',                        // just a normal required validation
    'lastname'         => 'required',                        // just a normal required validation
    'email'            => 'required|email|unique:users',     // required and must be unique in the users table
    'password'         => 'required',

    );
    $validationResponse=$this->validateForm($input,$rules);

    if($validationResponse=="passed"){


        $user=new \App\User;   
        $user->name=$input['name'];
        $user->email=$input['email'];
        $user->lastname=$input['lastname'];
        $user->password=\Hash::make($input['password']);
        $user->userlevel=isset($input['isAdmin'])?1:0;
        $user->save();

        return redirect('users');
}
else{
        return Redirect::to('users/create')
        ->withErrors($validationResponse)->withInput();


     }


   }

/*
*validate user form input
*/
function validateForm($input,$rules){

         // do the validation ----------------------------------
         // validate against the inputs from our form
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        // check if the validator failed -----------------------
        if ($validator->fails()) {

            // get the error messages from the validator
            $messages = $validator->messages();

            return $messages;
        } 
        else{
            return 'passed';
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is fine for accesing from the userController, but what if I have another controller say projectsController and I want to access the same funtion i.e. validateForm

Where I should put this common function and how can I access it from any controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel built in answer to this is [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation)

Just create a form request using `php artisan make:request UserCheck`, and put in your validation rules in the method `rules`

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */

public function rules() {
    return [
       'name'             => 'required',                        // just a normal required validation
       'lastname'         => 'required',                        // just a normal required validation
       'email'            => 'required|email|unique:users',     // required and must be unique in the users table
       'password'         => 'required',

    ]; }
```

And call it

```
/*
 * Store a user in database
 */
public function store(UserCheck $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...
}
```